# How can I skip deleting a folder but still sync the folder contents for an Web Deploy (msdeploy) sync?

Tags: msdeploy

Let's say I have a folder 'content' that (for some reason) may or may not be present in the source folder tree for a Web Deploy sync operation.

With what `skip` setting(s) can I have Web Deploy sync the contents of this folder (regardless of whether it exists; I can use another skip setting to control which files are synced) without also deleting the folder in the snyc target when it doesn't exist in the sync source?

[Note – the line breaks in the example commands are purely cosmetic.]

With this command, Web Deploy will attempt to delete the 'content' folder in the sync target (and fail if there are files in it):

```
msdeploy.exe
  -verb:sync
  -source:dirPath=%source%
  -dest:dirPath=%target%
  -skip:skipaction=Delete,objectname=filePath,absolutepath=\\content
```

With this command, (it appears that) Web deploy will skip deleting the 'content' folder in the sync target but it will also fail to sync any files within that folder (which is eminently reasonable actually):

```
msdeploy.exe
  -verb:sync
  -source:dirPath=%source%
  -dest:dirPath=%target%
  -skip:skipaction=Delete,objectname=dirPath,absolutepath=\\content
```

It's perfectly acceptable if there is in-fact no way to do this! (But I'd like some details or references about why that would be.)

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions:

1. Have a look at the `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` switch ([see rule descriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568992.aspx)).
2. You may need to include both of those skip params, per [this blog post](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/18/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/):

> ...delete rules on a child are only processed if the parent is not
>   being deleted. So if you skip a file but it’s containing directory
>   doesn’t exist on the source, the directory (and thus the file) will be
>   deleted anyway.

Also, remember the `absolutePath` param takes regex so some chars (like `.`) should be escaped.

Comment: What you quoted from the blog post matches what I observed; the problem, for what I was trying to do, is that solution [1] prevents *any* files or folders from being deleted; for solution [2], skipping the deletion of the containing directory/folder also seems to skip the child files.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible. If a skip delete rule prevents a folder from being deleted, then none of the child files in that folder will be deleted either, and thus the child files won't be synced (completely).

---

Thinking about this more, especially in light of jkoreska's answer, I think the solution I adopted isn't terrible. Basically the problem is that the source and target root folders may contain some subset of a set of folders, say for example the full set is *bin*, *content*, and *templates*.

The reason why I want to sync the contents of a folder that might not exist in the source (or target), is that I'd like to use the same Web Deploy command(s) for any number of instances of  sources and targets.

My solution was to simply guarantee that the source instances always contained the full set of folders, and thus all of the targets would too – after at least one execution of the Web Deploy command(s).